# Same key finding values

Tags: python

So if I want to find the same key and add up the values in a list of dictionary.

`[{'hello':10,'hi':2},{'hi':3}]` will return 5 if I'm finding the key name'hi'

Comment: Are all the dictionary items ints? Do you want this behaviour for all of them? What’s the context for this, how did you end up in this situation?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a list comprehension can solve this pretty easily.

```
x = [{'hello': 10, 'hi': 2}, {'hi': 3}, {'nohihere': 8}]

all_hi = sum(d.get('hi', 0) for d in x)

print(all_hi)
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dlist = [{'hello':10,'hi':2},{'hi':3}]
sum(map(lambda x: x.get('hi',0), dlist))
```

Comment: @GaneshKathiresan, it was downvoted because it was just broken.  You got to it after it was edited.  I assume it was edited after looking at other answers.  Did you upvote this simply to counteract my downvote?  If so why did you do that and not upvote the other answers here that were correct sooner, and not just the answers that copied others?

Answer (score -1):

you just need to check if each object has key with 'hi'

```
list = [{'hello':10,'hi':2},{'hi':3},{'nothi':4}]

sum = 0

for i in list:
  if 'hi' in i:
     sum += i['hi']

print(sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is another solution

```
my_dict = [{'hello':10,'hi':2},{'hi':3}]
common_keys = set.intersection(*map(set, my_dict))
summed_dict = {key: sum(d[key] for d in my_dict) for key in common_keys}
print(summed_dict)
```

o/p - `{'hi': 5}`

else you can use this

```
import functools as ft
my_dict = [{'hello':10,'hi':2},{'hi':3}]
print({k: sum(d[k] for d in my_dict) for k in ft.reduce(set.intersection, map(set, my_dict))})
```

o/p - `{'hi': 5}`

Comment: Using map and then loop again is a little too much